# Laravel: Specify Auth::guard() by Middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my application I have a separate guard for administrator.

I have created a helper function like this:

```
function admin_auth()
{
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::guard(config('admin.auth.guard'));
}
```

and  I use this method in my controllers and blade files for example like this:

```
if (admin_auth()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

or like this

```
<p>{{ admin_auth()->user()->email }}</p>
```

All controller and blade files from my admin dashboard are accessible under the route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
 //...
}
```

My question is: Is it possible that if and only if I call a controller or blade file with prefix `/admin` in the route, that the function `Auth()` will call `admin_auth()` ?

So that I could simplify my code to

```
<p>{{ Auth::user()->email }}</p>
```

I couldn't find that in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication) but I thought maybe this is possible via middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can just add a middleware to the route so only admins can access the page...?

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin'], ['prefix' => 'admin']], function () {
    //
});
```